# output is address instead of values

Tags: c, arrays, addition

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int i,limit,sum=0;
    int a[100];

    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
    printf("enter the limit");
    scanf("%d",&limit);
    printf("enter the values");
    for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[limit]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+a[i];
    }
    printf("the sum is : %d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
enter the limit3
enter the values3
3
3
the sum is : 19265880
```

The actual output should be 9

Comment: Please try to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your code. Where do `scanf("%d",&a[limit])` write the numbers it read?

Comment: `scanf("%d",&a[limit]);` should be `scanf("%d",&a[i]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&a[limit]); //replace limit with i
}
```

You can see that `scanf` is reading into the array `a[limit]` instead of `a[i]`. This is causing the issue.

Comment: It's also invoking *Undefined Behavior* because `limit` is one-past the end of the array...